# ASP.Net core RC2 identity, get user profile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to do a simple thing and i am new to asp.net, so i need advice what is the right approach, and how to do it.

i am trying to query a database with linq to get only the sales of the sales person that is currently logged in, so i added to the application user a property called salesCode and in the linq query i want to be able to say something like sale.Where(c => c.SalesCode == User.SalesCode), but i was not able to get the sales code of the user, is this usually a user claim, or role, or i need to get the user class and get the property salesCode from the user class, and if so how do i get the logged in user.

Note: i created a webSite from the ASP.Net Core templates in visual studio, and i'm using the templates default identity model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

If you did something like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string SalesCode { get; Set;}  
}
```

Then, in order to get a given user's SalesCode, you should retrieve the current User: 
 See how in the GetCurrentUserAsync method defined in the ManageController 
 and then access the SalesCode field.

Just ensure that your SalesCode field contains data

You may use the mechanism of Roles instead of SalesCode..

Comment: Thank you, and yes my user class was exactly like you wrote, and although the user manager did not have the property SalesCode your reference to the GetCurrentUserAsync method helped to go on the write direction.